# How to add a class directly on a unordered list element that is a primary navigation

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm working in Wordpress 4.9.5
For any WP navigation menu I create, what would be the best approach for adding a custom class name directly on the `<ul>` element? I need it on this element and prefer not to do javascript injections to add the class name to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav your_custom_class">%3$s</ul>',
));
```